# Not Able to Get Custom Post Type in Single and Single-custom-post-type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom post type called `projectsCPT` and I am able to display them on `page-projectsCPT.php`

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Projects
*/
 get_header(); 
?>
<div class="container" style="padding-top:35px;">
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'projectsCPT', 'posts_per_page' => 1000, 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC'  );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
$thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
$projectName = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vdw_gallery_name', true); 
echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">';
echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
  echo '<div class="panel-heading">'.$projectName.'</div>';
  echo '<div class="panel-body">';
    the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'img-responsive', 'href' =>$thumb_url));
  echo '</div>';
 echo '  <div class="panel-footer"><a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="'. get_the_permalink() .'" role="button">More Details</a></div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
endwhile;
    ?>        
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
```

but the

```
"><a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="'. get_the_permalink() .'" role="button">More Details</a>
```

is redirecting to `404.php` page!

I have a `single.php` and `single-projectsCPT.php` which I have repeated same code as `page-projectsCPT.php` to see if it is working but still getting to `404.php`

Comment: what does `get_the_permalink` output? have you reset your permalinks since creating the CPT?...

Comment: Hi David , can you lease let me know how to reset the permalinks?

Comment: The easiest way to reset them is in the admin console - just visiting the Settings .. Permalinks should be enough, though you could save the settings in that page for good measure

Comment: Hi, Go to settings > permalinks and then save the permalink structure as you need. this will reset the permalinks.

Comment: You wrote you repeated the same code in single-projectCPT.php file. I donot think you should do that. You donot need the $args or wp_query in single-projectCPT file.

Comment: Check your `register_post_type()` arguments to see if there is something there that you've set that could have do this...